# How to retrieve data from SQL Server and display as a task scheduler using asp.net and C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to create the attached task scheduler using asp.net and C#.

In SQL Server I have a table with these columns:

```
InstituteId, InstituteName, Address, 
CareerDay2017 (date), CareerDay2018 (date), CareerDay2019 (date)
```

Dropdown list has values 2017, 2018, 2019. A button should be next to the dropdownlist.

When we select the year from dropdown list and click the button particular data should be retrieved and displayed as the image.

The career day details should be retrieved and colored the particular cell.

[image]

This is what I have tried, but it is incorrect. Hope you have taken my idea and help me.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NAWODA;Initial Catalog=InternsDB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader sdr,sdr1, sdr2;
String query;

DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
String dateColumn;

StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchDetailPanel.Visible = false;
    searchTaskPanel.Visible = false;

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        con.Open();
        {
            query = @"SELECT InstituteId, InstituteName 
                      FROM Institution 
                      WHERE YEAR(CareerDay2018) = '2018' 
                      ORDER BY InstituteId";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            sdr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        setData(sdr1, currentDetailPanel);

        {
            query = @"SELECT CareerDay2017, CareerDay2018, CareerDay2019
                      FROM Institution 
                      ORDER BY InstituteId";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            sdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        createYearTable(sdr1, sdr2, currentTaskPanel);
    }
}

private void setData(SqlDataReader sdr, Panel DetailPanel1)
{
    table.Append("<table>");
    table.Append("<tr><th>Institute ID</th> <th>Institute Name</th>");
    table.Append("</tr>");

    if (sdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            table.Append("<tr>");
            table.Append("<td>" + sdr[0] + "</td>");
            table.Append("<td>" + sdr[1] + "</td>");
            table.Append("</tr>");
        }
    }

    table.Append("</table>");
    DetailPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });

    sdr.Close();
    sdr.Dispose();
}

private void createYearTable(SqlDataReader sdr1,SqlDataReader sdr2, Panel DetailPanel2)
{
    int currentYear = Int32.Parse(current.ToString("yyyy"));

    table.Append("<table>");

    //****filling the year
    table.Append("<tr>");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        table.Append("<td>" + Convert.ToString(currentYear) + "</td>");
    }

    table.Append("</tr>");

    //****filling the month
    table.Append("<tr>");

    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        int monthString = j;
        table.Append("<td>" +getMonthName(monthString) + "</td>");

    }
    table.Append("</tr>");

    //****data cell filling
    if (sdr2.HasRows)
    {
        while (sdr2.Read())
        {
            table.Append("<tr>");

            if (yearDropDownList.SelectedValue == "2017")
            {
                dateColumn = sdr2[5].ToString();

                DateTime careerFairDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateColumn);
                int monthNo = Int32.Parse(careerFairDate.ToString("MM"));
                int dateNo = Int32.Parse(careerFairDate.ToString("dd"));

                for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
                {
                    if (monthNo == j)
                    {
                        table.Append("<td>");
                        Label lbl1 = new Label();
                        lbl1.Text = "On" + dateNo;
                        table.Append("</td>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table.Append("<td>");
                        Label lbl2 = new Label();
                        table.Append("</td>");
                    }
                }
            }

            table.Append("</tr>");
        }

        table.Append("</table>");
        DetailPanel2.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });

        sdr2.Close();
        sdr2.Dispose();
    }
}

protected String getMonthName(int i)
{
    String[] monthName = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    return monthName[i - 1];
}

protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentDetailPanel.Visible = false;
    currentTaskPanel.Visible = false;
    searchDetailPanel.Visible = true;
    searchTaskPanel.Visible = true;

    con.Open();

    if (yearDropDownList.SelectedValue == "2018")
    {
        query = @"SELECT InstituteId, InstituteName 
                  FROM Institution 
                  WHERE YEAR(CareerDay2018) = '2018' 
                  ORDER BY InstituteId";
    }
    else if (yearDropDownList.SelectedValue == "2017")
    {
        query = @"SELECT InstituteId, InstituteName 
                  FROM Institution 
                  WHERE YEAR(CareerDay2017) = '2017' 
                  ORDER BY InstituteId";
    }
    else if (yearDropDownList.SelectedValue == "2019")
    {
        query = @"SELECT InstituteId, InstituteName 
                  FROM Institution  
                  WHERE YEAR(CareerDay2019) = '2019' 
                  ORDER BY InstituteId";
    }

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    setData(sdr, searchDetailPanel);

    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    createYearTable(sdr,sdr2,searchTaskPanel);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: Thank you @Kyle, I just paste my code above and it is not working.I am a beginner for those stuff I cannot identify the error.

Comment: What error are you getting? "This is what I have tried, but It is incorrect"

Comment: The cell coloring part is not working dear,and the Institution Name,Institution ID part display twice horizontally.

Comment: Side note: if you have an `INT` value (e.g. the return value of the `YEAR()` function), you should **NOT** compare it against a **string** in single quotes (you're just incurring unnecessary conversions that cost time) - compare it to an **INT** - without the quotes! So use this instead of what you have right now: `WHERE YEAR(CareerDay2017) = 2017`

Comment: @marc_s got it and thank you very much dear.

Answer (score 0):

As for the UI part, you need to place a breakpoint in the method that draws your UI and step through it while it is reading your data.  You need to learn how to debug you code.

Just based off what you have posted, I think you have a bigger issue, you should not be declaring a SqlConnection at the class level, it should be in a method somewhere.  For example:

```
public void GetCalendarData(int year)
{
    // You need to use a parameter for the year instead of hard-coding it (note the @year)
    string strCmd = @"SELECT InstituteId, InstituteName 
         FROM Institution 
         WHERE YEAR(CarrerDay2018) = @year 
           ORDER BY InstituteId";

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd))
    {
        // add the @year parameter to the command
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);

        conn.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // setdata, createYearTable, etc.

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

This way you are not holding a connection to the database for any longer than you need to.  Also, I have put the connection and the command inside using statements, meaning that they will be disposed of properly by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you and Can you give me an idea to cell coloring part?